# possible bug in `rbinom()` for large numbers of trials

Tags: r, random

I've been writing some code that iteratively performs binomial draws (using `rbinom`) and for some callee arguments I can end up with the size being large, which causes R (3.1.1, both official or homebrew builds tested—so unlikely to be compiler related) to return an unexpected `NA`.  For example:

```
rbinom(1,2^32,0.95)
```

is what I'd expect to work, but gives `NA` back.  However, running with `size=2^31` or `prob≤0.5` works.

The fine manual mentions inversion being used when `size < .Machine$integer.max` is false, could this be the issue?

Comment: It also occurs to me that there's a symmetry in binomial chances, i.e. "win = N- lose" ,so just do `K - rbinom(1,K,.05)`

Comment: I think @CarlWitthoft figured it out, at least in part. As you pointed out, R can't handle integers bigger than 2^32, and it isn't smart enough to know that `rbinom(1,2^32,0.95) == 1 - rbinom(1,2^32,0.05)`.

Comment: @ssdecontrol `R` handles large ints by casting them to `numeric` aka "double."  However, somewhere in the rbinom code, as Roland pointed out, something either got forced to `int` and blew up, or some other dumb thing happened.

Comment: I think the problem is in [src/library/stats/src/random.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/fbf5cdf29d923395b537a9893f46af1aa75e38f3/src/library/stats/src/random.c), where `rbinom` is defined via the `DEFRAND2_INT` macro, which coerces the result to integer when returning from C to R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/rbinom.c) `rbinom` does the equivalent (in C code) of the following for such large sizes:

```
qbinom(runif(n), size, prob, FALSE)
```

And indeed:

```
set.seed(42)
rbinom(1,2^31,0.95)
#[1] 2040095619
set.seed(42)
qbinom(runif(1), 2^31, 0.95, F)
#[1] 2040095619
```

However:

```
set.seed(42)
rbinom(1,2^32,0.95)
#[1] NA
set.seed(42)
qbinom(runif(1), 2^32, 0.95, F)
#[1] 4080199349
```

As @BenBolker points out `rbinom` returns an integer and if the return value is larger than `.Machine$integer.max`, e.g., larger than `2147483647` on my machine, `NA` gets returned. In contrast `qbinom` returns a double. I don't know why and it doesn't seem to be documented.

So, it seems like there is at least undocumented behavior and you should probably report it.

Comment: Thanks, it looked like a bug to me as well.  Will do something like @Ben suggests until a fix gets committed.

Comment: On second thought, I think the only "bug" is that the results of `rbinom()` are coerced to integer, which becomes NA when greater than `.Machine$integer.max`.  You could just use `qbinom(runif(n),size,prob)`, which would certainly be more compact than my answer.

Comment: @BenBolker That makes me wonder why `rbinom` returns an integer, but `qbinom` a numeric.

Comment: @Roland good point.  At the very least, then, it's an inconsistency. Sam, have you reported this?  It might be worth bringing it up on r-devel@r-project.org first ...

Answer (score 2):

I agree that (in the absence of documentation saying this is a problem) that this is a bug.  A reasonable workaround would be using the Normal approximation, which should be very very good indeed (and faster) for such large values.  (I originally meant this to be short and simple but it ended up getting a little bit out of hand.)

```
rbinom_safe <- function(n,size,prob,max.size=2^31) {
    maxlen <- max(length(size),length(prob),n)
    prob <- rep(prob,length.out=maxlen)
    size <- rep(size,length.out=maxlen)
    res <- numeric(n)
    bigvals <- size>max.size
    if (nbig <- sum(bigvals>0)) {
        m <- (size*prob)[bigvals]
        sd <- sqrt(size*prob*(1-prob))[bigvals]
        res[bigvals] <- round(rnorm(nbig,mean=m,sd=sd))
    }
    if (nbig<n) {
        res[!bigvals] <- rbinom(n-nbig,size[!bigvals],prob[!bigvals])
    }
    return(res)
}

set.seed(101)
size <- c(1,5,10,2^31,2^32)
rbinom_safe(5,size,prob=0.95)
rbinom_safe(5,3,prob=0.95)
rbinom_safe(5,2^32,prob=0.95)
```

The Normal approximation should work reasonably well whenever the mean is many standard deviations away from 0 or 1 (whichever is closer). For large N this should be OK unless p is *very* extreme.  For example:

```
n <- 2^31
p <- 0.95
m <- n*p
sd <- sqrt(n*p*(1-p))
set.seed(101)![enter image description here][1]
rr <- rbinom_safe(10000,n,prob=p)
hist(rr,freq=FALSE,col="gray",breaks=50)
curve(dnorm(x,mean=m,sd=sd),col=2,add=TRUE)
dd <- round(seq(m-5*sd,m+5*sd,length.out=101))
midpts <- (dd[-1]+dd[-length(dd)])/2
lines(midpts,c(diff(sapply(dd,pbinom,size=n,prob=p))/diff(dd)[1]),
      col="blue",lty=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't the normal approximation only recommended when `prob` is near 0.5?  I'd expect values between 0.7 and 0.975 to be used commonly.  I guess I could test to see if it works well enough!

Comment: see edits. (also see Wikipedia for more information on the Normal approx).

Answer (score 2):

This is the intended behaviour, but there are two issues:
1) The NA induced by coercion should raise a warning
2) The fact that discrete random variables have storage mode integer should be documented.

I have fixed 1) and will modify the documentation to fix 2) when I have a little more time.